# Have Grothendieck's notes in Montpellier already been investigated?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, soft-question, ho.history-overview

Grothendieck, who passed away on November 13, 2014, left a huge amount (around 20.000 sheets) of personal notes in the University of Montpellier that he thought he was the only one to be able to decipher. I heard that this intellectual treasure has been stored even though Grothendieck did not want anyone to publish any of his works.

My question is therefore: has someone begun to examine these notes?

Comment: I think Pierre Cartier must know. It is said in Wikipedia that "Over 20,000 pages of Grothendieck's mathematical and other writings, held at the University of Montpellier, remain unpublished[36] .They are now being digitized for preservation and will probably be made available to the mathematical community[37]".  Ref.36 is : (French) Le trésor oublié du génie des maths. Ref.37 is : (French) Les «gribouillis» d'Alexandre Grothendieck enfin sauvegardés . The two ref. are on line. May be you know all of this.

Comment: Possibly related: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/282871

Comment: The archives had been used in http://www.iaz.uni-stuttgart.de/LstAlg/Kuenzer/Kuenzer/sinh.html (as part of references to Hoàng Xuân Sính's work) and it was transcribed a letter to Deligne.

Comment: You can see here : https://agrothendieck.github.io/

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here is a book (in French) where it is explained in detail how all of Grothendieck's private manuscripts were transported to Paris in November 2015, and saved there in a secure library:

> Philippe Douroux, **Alexandre Grothendieck- Sur les traces du dernier
>   génie des mathématiques**.

Comment: It seems that Grothendieck's children want to be the first owners of all of  their father's manuscripts . What's for ? That's the question !

Comment: Weeks ago, the same author above, Ph. Douroux, published a long article in Le Monde 6/5/19 (french important news paper ) about Grothendieck's manuscripts (legacy). He is asking : What is the price  ?  45 000  ?  Who is the owner ? Grothendieck's five children ? The BNF (national french library) ? The question seems to be  still unresolved .

Answer (score 24):

Apparently 18,000 pages of Grothendieck's notes are going to be released on May 10, 2017 at 4:30 pm on the site of the University of Montpellier. I get this information from the following article: http://www.liberation.fr/sciences/2017/05/05/les-notes-du-mathematicien-alexandre-grothendieck-arrivent-sur-le-net_1567517

---

...and [here is a link](https://grothendieck.umontpellier.fr/) to the Université de Montpellier site where 18,000 of Grothendieck's notes are now posted!

Comment: Yes, I read this yesterday. Thank you anyway.

Comment: I can't help but I need to say this. I'm **overwhelmed**. It looks like the big math treasure chest. It is like looking over the genius shoulder...