# Grothendieck's manuscripts

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, soft-question, ho.history-overview

This is a curiosity question.

Some time ago, late Grothendieck's manuscripts have been uploaded, with consent from Grothendieck's family, for the community to consult.

They can be found here, following a link on the IHES webpage dedicated to Grothendieck (https://www.ihes.fr/en/tag/grothendieck/)

https://grothendieck.umontpellier.fr

Has anybody read through some part of them, and found anything interesting so far?

Comment: I have to confess that I tried to look at some of the material, and I found it unreadable.

Comment: Haha that's funny

Comment: What's funny? The OP asked a totally sensible question, with a somewhat historical flavor.

Comment: I'm aware of interesting mathematics in Récoltes et Semailles. See also here, Minhyong Kim's answer: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/48622/has-the-mathematical-content-of-grothendiecks-récoltes-et-semailles-been-used

Comment: This link deserves to be posted as a partial answer

Comment: A Grothendiek's student let me know that his manuscripts contain his homotopy theory of categories.

Comment: You can see here : https://agrothendieck.github.io/